# How do I stop an external library from clogging my output window in VS2012?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I've installed an IRC library (http://www.nuget.org/packages/SmartIrc4net/) using NuGet, and it's constantly catching `System.FormatException`s. In their code it's try-catch'd without doing anything with it, but everytime it occurs, my output window receives a `"A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll"` message.

I'm using the output window for checking debug messages, I don't want it to be clogged with messages I don't do anything with. Any way to hide them?

Comment: Easiest way is to debug the app and find out what  is causing the exception and fix it.

Comment: Having used NuGet, I only get the SmartIrc4Net.dll file though. Unless there is a way to get to the code inside the .dll to debug it? Of course I could always track down the original source code and compile that one myself, but I was hoping not to have to go -that- far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click in the debugger's output window and uncheck "Exception Messages". This will hide all exception messages, not just the one's from the 3rd party.